# Attributeerror: type object image has no attribute open in tkinter call back

Tags: python, tkinter, ocr

This question have been asked frequently, but **my case its different**.

I am developing an app that takes a screenshot of some videos, does OCR processing, and displays the subtitle to the user in list view.
I have used `tkinter` to display the text in `listview`.  Whenever I run my code I get `Attributeerror :type object image has no attribute open`.

#### my question:

Is it correct to display it in list view?
Is there an other way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

#### Here is my code:

```
import sys
import PIL.Image
sys.modules['Image'] = PIL.Image
import Image
import cv2
import pytesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import os
import re
import webbrowser
import requests
#import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from PIL import ImageGrab
import threading
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import lxml
from lxml import etree
a=""
root = Tk()
Lb1 = Listbox(root)

def printit():
  a=""
  im=ImageGrab.grab()
  image=np.array(im)
  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  crop_position = int(image.shape[0]/4)
  subtitle_img = image[image.shape[0] - crop_position:,:]
  rthresh,thresh = cv2.threshold(subtitle_img, 100,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  inverted = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
  imageFileName = "textImages.png"
  cv2.imwrite(imageFileName,inverted)
  curText = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(imageFileName))
  os.remove(imageFileName)
  return curText
def update_status():

  # Get the current message
  res=printit()
  Lb1.insert(res)
  # After 1 second, update the status
  root.after(1000, update_status)
root.after(1, update_status)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the `Image` of PIL or Tkinter? Because the one of PIL has an `open` method but you are importing the one of Tkinter which doesn't.

Comment: No that Image belongs to PIL.Thanks for reminding.I used PIL.Image.open(name) and the error resolved.

Comment: But when you do `from tkinter import *`, you replace PIL's `Image` by Tkinter's. So I advise you to do `import tkinter as tk`.